# Simulate wheel drag momentum/friction?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm building a spin-able wheel of fortune using d3 and javascript.  I have a sample of what I've made so far in a plunkr.  Right now I can drag the wheel along the mouse.  I also have a random spin() function.

http://plnkr.co/edit/SXSsiWDoUGjHVj98HF5F?p=preview

Here is the snippet of the code that has to do with the spinning and the mouse drag of the wheel:

```
    function spin(d){

    var  ps       = 360/data.length,
         pieslice = Math.round(1440/data.length),
         rng      = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1440) + 360);

    rotation = (Math.round(rng / ps) * ps);

    //TODO: click rightmost slice
    picked = 0;
    console.log(picked+1);

    rotation += 90 - Math.round(ps/2);

    vis.transition()
        .duration(3000)
        .attrTween("transform", rotTween)
        .each("end", function(){

            // //mark question as seen
            // d3.select(".slice:nth-child(" + (picked + 1) + ") path")
            //     .attr("fill", "#111");

            //populate question TODO
            d3.select("#question h1")
                .text(data[picked].label);

            oldrotation = rotation;
        });
}


var isDown = false;
var lastX = w / 2;
var lastY = h / 2;
var curAngle = 0;
var finishAngle = 0;
var angleDeg = 0;

container.on("mousedown", function(d) {
    isDown = true;
    var thisX = d3.event.x - lastX,
        thisY = d3.event.y - lastY;
    curAngle = Math.atan2(lastY - d3.event.y, lastX - d3.event.x) // * 180 / Math.PI) ;
    if (curAngle < 0) curAngle += 2 * Math.PI;
    curAngle = curAngle * 180 / Math.PI;
});
container.on("mousemove", function(d) {
    if (isDown) {
        var thisX = d3.event.x - lastX,
        thisY = d3.event.y - lastY;
    angleDeg = Math.atan2(lastY - d3.event.y, lastX - d3.event.x) // * 180 / Math.PI) - curAngle
    if (angleDeg < 0) angleDeg += 2 * Math.PI;
    angleDeg = angleDeg * 180 / Math.PI;
    angleDeg = angleDeg - curAngle + finishAngle;
    if (angleDeg < 0) angleDeg += 360; 
    container.attr("transform", "translate(" + (w / 2 + padding.left) + "," + (h / 2 + padding.top) + ") rotate(" + angleDeg + "," + 0 + "," + 0 + ")");
    }
});
container.on("mouseup", function(d) {
    finishAngle = angleDeg;
    //populate question TODO
    picked = 2;
    d3.select("#question h1")
        .text(data[picked].label);
    isDown = false;
```

Is there a way to modify the code and simulate (doesn't have to be real physics) some momentum of the wheel that slows down after the "mouseup" event happens?  I'm thinking about using the amount of time the "mousemove" was happening, but I'm not sure how I can use the amount of distance the wheel moves (especially when it has to do with the most recent movements of the wheel).